# How to convert JAXB class into xml in data weave?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

One of My java class return a JAXB Class of XML . In java i am able to write that class in to xml file . But how i will do it in dataweave.
I tried with below code .

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
read(payload.xml,'application/xml')
```

I want to return this xml as a response of service.
The payload.xml i am receiving in Transform as shown.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataWeave doesn't know how to process JAXB classes so probably that will not work. You should try to avoid using JAXB in Mule 4 applications, or if you can't avoid convert the result yourself in Java to plain Java objects or maps/lists combinations that DataWeave can parse and transforms.